# Scaling Application for video decoding using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, cpu-usage, rtsp

I am building an application to read multiple IP camera streams (rtsp) and run different Machine Learning Algorithms over it in real time. For each camera stream,

1. I spawn an ffmpeg process which continuously break the rtsp streams
   into frames and store them as images (JPEG). The streams use H.264
   encoding. I am taking 1 frame every second as output.
2. Message queues corresponding to models are given the message
   containing location of the file.
3. Models keep on picking up the file and drawing inferences

The problem I am facing is the CPU usage by ffmpeg decoding process. For real time inference without any loss of frames, I have to beef up my server by a core for every 2 camera streams. Is there any optimization I am missing for ffmpeg?

I am using Intel Xeon Gold processor with Ubuntu 18.04 OS

Comment: https://programming.vip/docs/using-gpu-hardware-to-speed-up-ffmpeg-video-transcoding-and-pit-draining.html  goto GPU for slo ffmpeg

Comment: Thank you. Already considered but that is currently not an options.

Comment: Can you use "-preset ultrafast" or reduce the frame size?